# Dropbox API C# Folder List Fails

Tags: c#

I am using the example code:

```
 using (var temp = new DropboxClient("My Access Token"))
            {
                var list = await temp.Files.ListFolderAsync("");

                // show folders then files
                foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFolder))
                {
                Console.WriteLine("D  {0}/", item.Name);
            }

            foreach (var item in list.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFile))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("F{0,8} {1}", item.AsFile.Size, item.Name);
            }
        }
```

I get a empty list.  What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have anything in the root directory of the account the token is for?

Answer (score 0):

The App Folder was indeed empty.  Thanks